# Split text into groups based on a certain character sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split a text into groups on a special character match.

For example, the following text should be divided into three parts, splitting on each `m=` match:

```
v=0 o=NNMAS 8571 287 IN IP4
t=1358416438 0
m=audio 43538 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 96 97
c=IN IP4
a=sendrecv
m=audio 43538 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 96 97
c=IN IP4
```

should become

1:

```
v=0 o=NNMAS 8571 287 IN IP4
t=1358416438 0
```

2:

```
m=audio 43538 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 96 97
c=IN IP4
a=sendrecv
```

3:

```
m=audio 43538 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 96 97
c=IN IP4
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are the lines starting with `s=` and `e=` coming from in your first split? And why is there `c=IN IP4` twice in the second split? Also, which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to split on the regex `(?m)^(?=m=)`.

**Explanation:**

```
(?m)  # Turn on multiline mode (so the next line works correctly).
^     # Assert position at the start of the line.
(?=   # Assert that the following text can be matched at the current position:
 m=   #  m=
)     # End of lookahead assertion.
```

You need to tell us which regex engine you're using so we can provide a working code sample.

In JavaScript, the mode modifiers need to go outside of the regex, so you get:

```
result = subject.split(/^(?=m=)/m);
```

Comment: thank you so much  i will use it for one of my Javascript object. XRegExp in this case